# How to find and Replace a token in a c# string that starts with a value

Tags: c#, replace, find

I've got an issue where I am applying a template to an object and am using a find and replace function to mesh the template in the form of a string of html.  The issue is, the height and width of the image are contained in the token so I don't have a way to find and replace as it could vary.

Token value is [ARTICLEIMAGE:150:200]

```
foreach(var article in articles) {
    var articleTemplateValue = _TemplateArticleMarkup;
    articleTemplateValue = articleTemplateValue.Replace("[ARTICLEIMAGE:xx:yy]", "<img src=" + article.ArticleImageFolder + "/" + article.ArticleImage + " title=" + article.ArticleTitle + " width="
        xx" height="
        yy" />");
}
```

This obviously would not work for every example as the dimensions of the image token will vary.  Is there a way to find the token as a StartsWith and then split the dimensions an array on the :.  Please let me know if that makes sense as it is a little confusing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex will solve this issue for you.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Then change your code as seen below.

```
foreach (var article in articles)
{
    string articleTemplateValue = _TemplateArticleMarkup;

    MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(articleTemplateValue, @"\[ARTICLEIMAGE\:(\d+)\:(\d+)\]");

    if (mc.Count > 0)
    {
        string toReplace = mc[0].Value;
        string xx = mc[0].Groups[1].Value;
        string yy = mc[0].Groups[2].Value;

        articleTemplateValue = articleTemplateValue.Replace(toReplace, "<img src=\"" + article.ArticleImageFolder + "/" + article.ArticleImage + "\" title=\"" + article.ArticleTitle + "\" width=\"" + xx + "\" height=\"" + yy + "\"/>");
     }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and while the other approaches worked, this fit in to my application a bit better.  Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Split()` command to find the width and the height. A very rough approach follows:

[rextester remo](http://rextester.com/BAXP20021)

```
String articleTemplateValue = "[test:40:200]";

Console.WriteLine(articleTemplateValue);

var arr = articleTemplateValue.Split(':');
if (arr.Length == 3) {
    var xx = arr[1];
    var yy = arr[2].Substring(0, arr[2].Length - 1);

    articleTemplateValue = articleTemplateValue.Replace(articleTemplateValue, "<img src=" 
       + "folder" + "/" + "image" + " title=" + "ArticleTitle" + " width="+ xx + " height= " + yy+  "/>");

    Console.WriteLine(articleTemplateValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @giorgos-altanis This works great for the simple image but what if I had additional tokens and markup within my template such as - <div id='ImageWrapper'>[test:40:200]</div><div id='DateWrapper'>[POSTEDDATE:mm/dd/yyyy]</div>  It doesn't render properly when I played with it in the rextester.

Comment: Then you would have a different problem :-) Anyway, the regular expressions approach is much more elegant and "economic".

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex would do the trick [repl.it demo](https://repl.it/GCng/0)

1. `"\[ARTICLEIMAGE:\d+?:\d+?\]"`
2. `\[` escape the [ character. Brackets are special characters in Regex
3. `\d` any digit
4. `\d+?:` **+** **is 0 or more digits**. Until we find a colon :. The ? means non-greedy and is really not needed...
5. `\]` escape the closing bracket

---

```
var matches = Regex.Match(articleTemplateValue, @"\d+");
    var xx = matches;
    var yy = matches.NextMatch();
    var template = "<img src=" + article.ArticleImageFolder + "/" + article.ArticleImage + " title=" + article.ArticleTitle + " width="
        + xx + " height="
        + yy + " />";
    articleTemplateValue = articleTemplateValue = Regex.Replace(articleTemplateValue, @"\[ARTICLEIMAGE:\d+?:\d+?\]", template);
```

Using

- [Regex.Match(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Regex.Replace(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Joe - this is great.  I'm just scratching my head a bit on why it works.  What if I wanted to add another token say that represented a date that included varying formating. Example would be: "<div id='MyId' class='dateWrapper'>[Date:mm/dd/yyyy]</div><div id='MyId' class='imageWrapper'>[ARTICLEIMAGE:72:50]</div>"  Could I use the same method to replace and format that date or would it just hit on the d+?

Comment: Also - could a similar syntax work on formatting the date?

Comment: Yes, Dates are commonly parsed with Regex if the original format is known. `\[Date:\d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d/]` for the replace and `"\d{2.4}"` to match the month, day, and year